# Why variable outside for loop doesn't work?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop which stores results in an int array and from these results I need to be able to search for eg. how many 1 are in the array so I declared an int variable outside the loop but it keeps saying that my array hasn't been initialized. Could you guys help me thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class TestDie {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Die firstDie = new Die();
    int[] playerOneResults;

    firstDie.roll();
    System.out.println(firstDie.getFaceValue());

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PLease enter the name of player one");
    String playerOneName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of player two");
    String playerTwoName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of dice to be thrown");
    int numDice = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("First player's name: " + playerOneName);
    System.out.println("Second player's name: " + playerTwoName);
    System.out.println("Number of dice will be thrown: " + numDice);

    for(int counter = 0; counter != numDice; counter++)
    {
        playerOneResults = new int[numDice];
        firstDie.roll();
        playerOneResults[counter] = firstDie.getFaceValue();
        System.out.println("Player one results: " + playerOneResults[counter]);         
    }

    Arrays.sort(playerOneResults);
    int c = Arrays.binarySearch(playerOneResults, 1);
    System.out.println(c); 


}
}
```

Comment: Because when you declare a variable inside a loop it gets destroyed when you exit the loop. To use it outside the loop simply declare it outside the loop.

Comment: @James Thanks mate! I don't understand why a variable inside a loop gets destroyed when we exit the loop so am i correct to say that the loop is actually for repetitive manipulations only? thanks!

Comment: @alan-ogz83 Honestly, I don't know why they get destroyed, but that's just the way java is, so just remember that if you want to use a variable after you exit a loop just declare it outside.

Comment: @James The body of the loop might not have been executed, the state of any variables declared within the body of the loop therefore can't be known outside it. Far safer to let them pass out of scope instead of dealing with possibly uninitialised variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Die firstDie = new Die();
    int[] playerOneResults = null;

    firstDie.roll();
    System.out.println(firstDie.getFaceValue());

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PLease enter the name of player one");
    String playerOneName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of player two");
    String playerTwoName = userInput.next();

    System.out.println("Enter the number of dice to be thrown");
    int numDice = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.println("First player's name: " + playerOneName);
    System.out.println("Second player's name: " + playerTwoName);
    System.out.println("Number of dice will be thrown: " + numDice);

    playerOneResults = new int[numDice];

    for (int counter = 0; counter != numDice; counter++) {
        firstDie.roll();
        playerOneResults[counter] = firstDie.getFaceValue();
        System.out.println("Player one results: " + playerOneResults[counter]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(playerOneResults);
    int position=0;
    while(position<0){
        int c = Arrays.binarySearch(playerOneResults, position,playerOneResults.length-1, 1);
        position=c;
        System.out.println(c);
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks mate for your help manage to get it sorted now. but i have another problem now. it only searches for the first element which has got 1. are we able to list out all the 1s? or better still say how many 1s are there in the array? Thanks!

Comment: Use binarySearch(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, float key) method instead.

Comment: I changed the code for your request

Comment: thanks so much for your efforts mate but it doesn't seem to print out the total number of 1 i think int c is not working there. :)

Comment: @user3717646 Can you explain your answer.